# Slug duplicates once clicking on link

Tags: php, html, slug

I'm using [polylang](https://he.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) plugin.

I have the current URL `http://localhost/wordpress/en/` in my browser, I have another URL that suppose to change language to Hebrew  `http://localhost/wordpress/he/`.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/en/">English</a>
<a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/he/">hebrew</a>
```

Everytime I click on another link, I receive the following:

`http://localhost/wordpress/he/en/`

(it just adds slug over another slug instead replacing it)

How can I prevent slug duplication on URL address?

Comment: Remove the `en`. `<a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">English</a>`

Comment: @shanebp I think you miss understood, I want to have `en` slug and `he` which another language. right now I receive `domain.com/en/he/` instead of replacing `en` it addon it.

Comment: @shanebp edited my post.

Comment: Does your home url include the `en`? If so, remove it.

Comment: @shanebp no, it's just `domain.com`. I click on english once, it turns to `domain.com/en/`, then if I click hebrew it becomes `domain.com/en/he/`.